# Number of ways to pick 12 elements from 3 different kinds of different no of elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question:**

A florist has 5 aspidistras, 6 buttercups, and 7 chrysanthemums. How many different kinds of bouquets of a dozen flowers (it is not required to use all types of flowers) can she make from these?

**My Solution:**
The solution I came up with is as follows:

Since it seems that the order of flowers doesn't matter, thus we can just add them all up and choose a dozen flowers out of them.

5 aspidistras + 6 buttercups + 7 chrysanthemums = 18 total flowers

answer = 18 choose 12 = 18564

Is the above answer correct or if not can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, if the flowers of the same type are indistinguishable, I cant add them up altogether and choose from them? Could you explain how that will affect the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be the number of aspidistras, $b$ be the number of buttercups, and $c$ be the number of chrysanthemums.  The number of ways of forming a bouquet of a dozen flowers is the number of solutions of the equation
$$a + b + c = 12 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $a \leq 5$, $b \leq 6$, and $c \leq 7$.

A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of twelve ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $a = 4$, $b = 5$, and $c = 3$, while 
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $a = 0$, $b = c = 6$.  The number of such solutions is 
$$\binom{12 + 2}{2} = \binom{14}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the fourteen positions required for twelve ones and two addition signs will be filled by addition signs.

In general, the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k = n$$
has 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers since a particular solution corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, and we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions required for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Now, we must subtract the number of solutions that violate one or more of the constraints.  Notice that it is not possible to violate two constraints simultaneously since $6 + 7 = 13 > 12$.

Suppose $a > 5$.  Then $a' = a - 6$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $a' + 6$ for $a$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
a' + 6 + b + c & = 12\\
a' + b + c & = 6 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{6 + 2}{2} = \binom{8}{2}$$
solutions.

Suppose $b > 6$.  Then $b' = b - 7$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $b' + 7$ for $b$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
a + b' + 7 + c & = 12\\
a + b' + c & = 5 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{5 + 2}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
solutions.

Suppose $c > 7$.  Then $c' = c - 8$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $c' + 8$ for $c$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
a + b + c' + 8 & = 12\\
a + b + c' & = 4 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{4 + 2}{2} = \binom{6}{2}$$
solutions.

Hence, the number of bouquets that can be formed is 
$$\binom{14}{2} - \binom{8}{2} - \binom{7}{2} - \binom{6}{2} = 27$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

I am a little confused about how you formed equation 2. Can you please explain how you came up with the equation a′ = a − 6?

Comment: Sure.  Since $a$ is an integer and $a > 5$, then $a \geq 6$.  Therefore, $a' = a - 6$ is a nonnegative integer.  The formula I stated applies to nonnegative integers, so we wish to manipulate the given equation into a form where we can apply the formula in order to count those cases that violate the restriction.

Comment: But the question says that a < 5 so how can we say a > 5 then a ≥ 6?

I apologize my questions might seem stupid but I am having trouble understanding the 2nd half of the question.

Comment: My strategy was to count all solutions of the equation $a + b + c = 12$ in the nonnegative integers, then remove those that violate the constraints.  One constraint is that $a \leq 5$, which we violate if $a > 5$.  Since $a$ is an integer, this means we violate the constraint if $a \geq 6$.  In solving equation 2, I found the number of solutions that violate the constraint $a \leq 5$.

Comment: I understand your solution now. Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

I count 27 different bouquets.

Let A,B,C denote the different flower names.

Ways that include only two types of flowers:

1. --- 7 C's and 5 A's
2. --- 7 C's and 5 B's
3. --- 6 C's and 6 B's

Ways that include three types of flowers:

4. --- 7 C's, 4 A's, 1 B
5. --- 7 C's, 4 B's, 1 A
6. --- 7 C's, 3 A's, 2 B's
7. --- 7 C's, 3 B's, 2 A's
8. --- 6 C's, 5 A's, 1 B
9. --- 6 C's, 5 B's, 1 A
10. --- 6 C's, 4 A's, 2 B's
11. --- 6 C's, 4 B's, 2 A's
12. --- 6 C's, 3 A's, 3 B's
13. --- 6 B's, 5 A's, 1 C
14. --- 6 B's, 5 C's, 1 A
15. --- 6 B's, 4 A's, 2 C's
16. --- 6 B's, 4 C's, 2 A's
17. --- 6 B's, 3 A's, 3 C's
18. --- 5 C's, 5 B's, 2 A's
19. --- 5 C's, 5 A's, 2 B's
20. --- 5 B's, 5 A's, 2 C's
21. --- 5 C's, 4 B's, 3 A's
22. --- 5 C's, 4 A's, 3 B's
23. --- 5 B's, 4 A's, 3 C's
24. --- 5 B's, 4 C's, 3 A's
25. --- 5 A's, 4 B's, 3 C's
26. --- 5 A's, 4 C's, 3 B's
27. --- 4 A's, 4 B's, 4 C's

Comment: Thank you for the help. I feel that both the answers provided (your answer and "N. F. Taussig" answer) are correct, they are just based on different interpretation of the question.
Your answer applies if we say that all aspidistras are same, all buttercups are same and all chrysanthemums are same.